# How to refresh Eclipse's launch configuration menu?

Tags: eclipse, executable-jar

I have a project called `Test1`, with a package `package1`, with a class `Class1` (which has a main method). I want to export it as a runnable JAR, but it's not in the list of launch configurations. The list does contain classes and projects that no longer exist, however. How do I get the list to refresh?

Edit: huh, turns out you have to run a class before it shows up in the launch configuration menu. Still, it'd be neat to get the whole menu to refresh so it's doesn't fill up with deleted classes. Updated title to emphasize the aspect of the question that's still relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the Project where you have the Problem, then Properties/Run/Debug Settings.

Under Launch configurations for "your Project":
simply remove existing configurations and add them named as you want to have them.

if you now take a look into the Export menu you will find your new running configurations.

greetings.

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work for already deleted projects though. I had two launch configurations "Test - Test" and "Test2 - Test", and the project Test was deleted. However, it worked to simply create a new project called Test and go into its properties as above, and "Test" and "Test2" were there in the list.